# how to use gnome library in xamarin studio?

Tags: c#, windows, xamarin, monodevelop, gnome

I starting project C# in Xamarin Studio gtk#.

I want to use gnome library in my project but this library is not found in my project. This is my code:

```
public static Gdk.Pixbuf GetIcon(string filename, int size) 
{
    string mimeType = Gnome.Vfs.Mime.TypeFromName(filename); 

    Gnome.IconLookupResultFlags result; 
    string iconName = Gnome.Icon.Lookup(IconTheme.Default, null, null,  null, null,
                                        mimeType, Gnome.IconLookupFlags.None, out result); 

    if (IconTheme.Default.HasIcon(iconName))
            return IconTheme.Default.LoadIcon(iconName, size, IconLookupFlags.UseBuiltin); 

    return null; 
}
```

I cannot build my application because gnome library is not found in my solution.
How do I add gnome library in my solution as reference? Can I download gnome library?

Comment: http://mono-project.com/FAQ:_General#Mono_and_GNOME

Comment: that faq explains the relationship between Mono and Gnome but doesn't state what library you're interested in, there are many gnome libraries for Mono

Comment: i cannot find gnome-sharp.dll

Comment: finally! a library name! thanks, it is here: https://github.com/mono/gnome-sharp.git you can compile it yourself

Comment: thank you friend.now how can i build this on windows? this is source and not found dll s

Comment: I don't know, I've never used Gnome on windows

Answer (score 0):

Gnome is primarily a Linux thing. So in your case you will have to find a Linux machine, install Mono and MonoDevelop, and then you should be able to develop GTK# application with Gnome integration.

[Gnome#](https://github.com/mono/gnome-sharp) can be built on Linux via make (as its readme document indicates). And once built, you can add it as a reference.